# How can I select the divs elements that not having another divs inside it?

Tags: java, html, information-retrieval, jsoup

I'm using Java and Jsoup to parse HTML pages and I want to get all the divs that not contains another divs inside it to print the text it contains.

But for example, if a div contains a table, and the table costains a div, I don't want it. I want only the div at the most bottom level, with none another div inside it (another tags are ok).

How I do this?

Primarilly, I want to know if there is some syntax that can I use with the `select()` method.

Comment: have a look at using regex. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc; //comes as parameter

Elements divs = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
for(Element div: divs){
    if(div.getElementsByTag("div").size() == 1){
        //is a div with no divs inside it
    }
}
```